# Binomial Coefficient Solve for n Where $_{20} C_{n+2} = _{20} C_{ 2n-1} $

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-coefficients

Trying to find the value of n.

$$_{20} C_{n+2} = _{20} C_{ 2n-1} $$

or

$$\mathrm{C}^{20}_{n+2} = \mathrm{C}^{20}_{2n-1}$$

Comment: You try to solve $\displaystyle \binom {z} {x} = \binom {z} {y}$, so you may in turns try to solve $x = y$ and $x = z - y$ with the conditions that the solutions will give $x, y \in \{0, 1, \ldots, z\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $_{20}C_{20} = _{20}C_{0}$.

Second hint: $_{20}C_{5} = _{20}C_{15}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am trying but not getting anywhere. more help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you see in the hints I gave you? What's a relationship between $5,15,$ and $20$?

Comment: 20 C (20 - n - 2)  =  20 C n + 2 right?

Comment: @user3444770 Yep.Just solve your question now using these

Comment: $${20! \over (20-n-1)!(n+1)!}= {20! \over (n+1)!(20-n-1)!}.$$ 

both sides cancel out each other, how would I solve for n?

Comment: @user3444770 refer to BGM's comment above. Try going by that way and you will get your answer

Comment: @user3444770 Good observation! But you also know that one of the subscripts equals $2n-1$. What can you do with that piece of information? (One subscript equals $20$ minus the other subscript.)

Comment: initially I was able to get to this equation but didnt know what to do next:

$${20! \over (20-n-1)!(n+1)!}= {20! \over (2n-1)!(20-2n+1)!}.$$

$${1 \over (20-n-1)!(n+1)!}= {1 \over (2n-1)!(20-2n+1)!}.$$

Comment: Something's weird. I'm thinking $n$ should be an integer, but it's not turning out that way.

Comment: By simple arithmetic, there is no solution.  $\binom{20}{n+2}=\binom{20}{2n-1},\ but\ (n+2)+(2n-1)=20,\ or\ 3n=19$, impossible!